# I can not access a has_one image from a VirtualPage conatiner when looping

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have a page type

> ProductPage

that $has_one FeatureImage

There is a virtual page that references one of the ProductPages

**When I am in a page that loops the children where one of the children is the virtual page I can render all fields except the FeatureImage field.**

```
class ProductPage extends Page
{
    private static $db = [
        'TeaserText'=>'Varchar'
    ];

    private static $has_one = [
        'LinkedProduct'=>'Product', 
        'FeatureImage'=>Image::Class
    ];
    private static $many_many = [

    ];
    private static $owns = [
       'FeatureImage'
    ];

    public function getCMSFields(){
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $featureField = UploadField::create('FeatureImage', 'Feature Image')->setFolderName('FeatureImages')->setDescription("This image appears in the category pages. 400x400px");
        $teaserField = TextField::create('TeaserText', 'Teaser Text')->setDescription("This text appears in the category pages");
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $featureField, 'Metadata');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $teaserField, 'Metadata');

        $productLinkField = DropdownField::create('LinkedProductID', 'Link a Product', Product::get()->map('ID', 'ProductName'));
        $productLinkField->setEmptyString('(Select one)');        

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $productLinkField, 'Content');

        $productLinkField->addExtraClass('stacked');
        $featureField->addExtraClass("stacked");
        $teaserField->addExtraClass("stacked");

        return $fields; 
    }
}
```

The SS template

```
<% loop $Children %>
    <div class="category-card mb-5">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-4">

                <img src="$FeatureImage.URL" class="fluid-image"/>
//This renders for standard ProductPage children

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 category-card-body">
               <h4 class="category-card-title"><a href="$Link">$MenuTitle</a></h4>
                <p class="category-card-text">$TeaserText</p>
//This TeaserText renders fine.

                <a href="$Link" class="category-card-link btn btn-info">view details</a>
             </div>                                           
        </div>
    </div>                           
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: Are you sure the image is accessible, eg. published? Does it show up on the matching `ProductPage`?

Comment: Yes... It is published and I can see it in the actual page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be an edge use case but I think it is valid and will post my solution for anyone else needing to do the same thing.

VirtualPage class will pull all database fields but it will not pull has_one relations so you can not access it from the virtual page.

From VirtualPage.php:

```
* Note: This Only duplicates $db fields and not the $has_one etc..
```

My solution is to include a method in the virutal page class that will return the actual parent page object **using <% with %>**

```
public function getTheParentPageObject(){
    $page = DataObject::get_by_id(SiteTree::class, $this->getField('CopyContentFromID'));   
    return $page;
}
```

This allows me to call the method inside my loop in the template and pull all fields that were left out of virtualization

```
    <% loop $Children %>
        <div class="category-card mb-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">                       

                    <% if $ClassName == "SilverStripe\CMS\Model\VirtualPage" %>
                        <% with $getTheFeaturedImageById() %>
                            <img src="$FeatureImage.URL" class="fluid-image"/>
                        <% end_with %>

                        <% else %>
                        <img src="$FeatureImage.URL" class="fluid-image"/>

                    <% end_if %>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 category-card-body">                        
                    <h4 class="category-card-title"><a href="$Link">$MenuTitle</a></h4>
                    <p class="category-card-text">$TeaserText</p>
                    <a href="$Link" class="category-card-link btn btn-info">view details</a>
                </div>                                           
            </div>
        </div>                           
    <% end_loop %>
```